# Animation freezes while AsyncTask loads data

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have a simple animation of a hearthBeat, whhile this animation is playing (infinite) I execute an asynctask , but at the time I execute the asynctask my animation starts to freeze and not keep animating untill `onPostExecute` is done

```
private Animation beat;
  beat = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashActivity.this,
                R.anim.heartbeat);

        new preLoadSplashScreen().execute();
```

And then in my AsyncTask

```
  public class preLoadSplashScreen extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            txtLoading.setText("Loading...");
            findViewById(R.id.logo_inicial).startAnimation(beat);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Json.getInstance().initJsonArrays();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            accessDashboard();
        }
    }
```

Even if I attach an animation listener I get the animation freeze as well

Is there anyway to keep playing the animation in a different thread while my background task do its job untill it finishes ?

If I place a `ProgressBar` it will keep spinning untill all my background task is done, but not this animation

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, but my guess is that the majority of work being done is in the `accessDashboard()` method. The `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI thread, so any other UI operations will be delayed until it finishes. All of your heavy processing or blocking operations need to be done in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Thanks Larry, will see whats going on there

Comment: accessDashboard only has an startActivity

Comment: My favorite technique is to break into the debugger ("pause" button) while the problem is occurring. Then you can examine the call stack for the main thread, which will give you some insight into what it's doing instead of running the animation. That is, assuming your animation isn't working because the whole UI is locked up.

Comment: @CoffeeBreak if `accessDashboard()` is calling `startActivity()`, then your current activity will be paused and no longer shown on screen.  Your animation won't matter at that point.